# redshift subquery reference issue - self join and min

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that works well on a standard sql, but redshift has restrictions that doesn't allow for queries that reference outer query info within the inner select.

The basic idea of the query is to produce diff for a timestamp from the last time this customer posted a response. I have customer post timestamps from a forum and I want to know when they post, what was the difference in time since the last time they posted. Here's the query running on test data in sql, with expected output: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04358/2

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
  current.id,
  current.datetime,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, current.datetime, IFNULL(next.datetime, 
current.datetime)) as diff
FROM
  TestTable as current
LEFT JOIN
  TestTable as next
    on next.datetime = (select min(datetime) from TestTable
      where datetime > current.datetime and id = current.id)
order by
  current.id, current.datetime
```

In redshift, this does not work since the subquery pattern is not supported. Any ideas how to turn this into a non-referential sub-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need derived tables. Use the window function [`first_value`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_firstlast_WF.html) to get the last time an id posted a comment and use it for subtraction.

```
SELECT
id,
datetime,
DATEDIFF(minute, datetime, first_value(datetime) over(partition by id order by datetime desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)) as diff
FROM TestTable
```

I'm not sure if a window function works inside another function in Redshift. In that case try,

```
SELECT
id,
datetime,
DATEDIFF(minute, datetime, last_response_time) as diff
FROM (SELECT t.*,first_value(datetime) over(partition by id order by datetime desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as last_response_time
      FROM TestTable t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks. This would be much easier. There's a syntax error somewhere in this line, trying work it out now.

Comment: Fiddling with the right syntax still, not sure what's wrong, but here's the update with your query, you see the syntax failure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04358/13

Comment: this syntax doesn't work with mysql.are you not using redshift?

Comment: You're right, I am using redshift and they overlap in syntax but are not the same. I still get the syntax error in redshift, which is why I mentioned it. Haven't figured out why. I'm running the above code on redshift (using datediff instead of timestampdiff for redshift functionality) and getting this error: Error running query: The query was malformed: (u'ERROR', u'42601', u'syntax error at or near "BETWEEN"', u'363',...

Comment: I'm not sure either. Might be a version issue or something else on my side. Regardless, thanks for pointing me in this direction, away from self-joins, I ended up using LEAD with OVER for the partition and got it working: LEAD(datetime, 1) OVER (partition by id order by datetime) as datetime_next

Comment: see the edit if it works. or remove `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` from the window function and check.

Comment: Nice, that works now "rows Between". Much appreciated.